# Simple Constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I've downloaded simple code with constructors. Could anyone explain me this part of code:

```
class Myclass
{
private:
    int x;
    double *y;                      

public:
    Myclass(int X);              

};

Myclass::Myclass(int X) : x(X)
{
y = new double[x];
}
```

I don't understand "Myclass::Myclass(int X) **:x(X)**". Couldn't it be written simpler?

Comment: What do you define as simpler?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Comment: Without writing :x(X). I don't understand this part.

Comment: Ok, Ilya gave me the answer.

Comment: @AdamMadamski get used to that syntax. For your `int` member is trivial, but there are entities in C++ where it is required (const members, reference members, non-default-constructibles, etc).  It is fundamentally more efficient to construct-as-wanted rather then default-construct and assign-as-wanted. Don't try to avoid it: *embrace it*.

Answer (score 4):

I guess from the bold face that it's just the `: x(X)` part you don't understand.

That's the *initialiser list*, used to initialise member variables. In this case, it initialises the variable `x` to have the same value as the constructor parameter `X`. `y` is not included in the list, so it's left uninitialised at that point, then assigned a value in the constructor body.

There's no simpler way to initialise a member variable (in a class with a non-trivial constructor).

Comment: Arguably, aggregate initialisation is simpler ;)

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: True, but not for this class since it needs a non-trivial constructor.

Comment: Right, but you didn't constrain your summary! hehe

Answer (score 4):

You can't write it any simpler without altering the effect of the code.

You *could* write it this way:

```
Myclass::Myclass(int X)
{
    x = X;
    y = new double[x];
}
```

But then it wouldn't be an *initialization* of `x`, it would be an *assignment* to `x`.

Each member variable is initialized before running the constructor body (the part between `{` and `}`), in the so-called [*member initialization list*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor) between the `:` and the `{`.

---

As a side note, it would be better to initialize `y` in the member initialization list as well, rather than assigning to it in the constructor body:

```
Myclass::Myclass(int X) : x(X), y(new double[x])
{
}
```

Comment: Try declaring the member as "const int x;", and then you'll see the difference between initialization and assignment.